# Transfer Logins Task SSIS Error

Tags: sql, ssis, database-administration

I'm working on a parallel upgrade of a Server from SQL 2008 to SQL 2014. I'm moving only few databases to the new instance. While transferring logins through Transfer Logins Task from SSIS, the package fails with the error, 
"Windows NT user or group 'user' not found. The user might have left the company and this domain user is not valid anymore. How can i skip such logins and complete the transfer?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to skip those logins within the SSIS task, but there are two options available to you:

- In the Transfer Logins Task Editor, select 'SelectedLogins' for LoginsToTransfer, and then manually choose which logins you wish to transfer.
- Clean up orphaned logins on the source server before doing the transfer. Articles such as https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1864/identify-orphaned-windows-logins-and-groups-in-sql-server-with-spvalidatelogins/ can help you find orphaned domain users in your SQL instance.

Comment: Thank you @Leonard!